# "npm install" taking forever to finish

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

First of all I have a very good computer and very good internet connection, so the problem cannot be there. I don't know when or how but suddenly I'm having to wait 15min for an `npm install` that would have taken less than a minute a little time ago. I ran `npm install` in this project:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "wave",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^6.6.1",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
(ommited for breviety)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@emotion%2fstylis 1894ms (cache revalidated)
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠹ idealTree:wave: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@emotion%2fstylis 1894ms (cache revalidated)
```

And a few minutes later:

```
(ommited for breviety)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@emotion%2fstylis 1894ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fplugin-transform-react-jsx-source 139323ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fplugin-transform-react-jsx-self 139344ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-module-imports 139342ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2ftraverse 139348ms (cache revalidated)
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠹ idealTree:wave: npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2ftraverse 139348ms (cache revalidated)
```

That happens many times during any install: it fetches a lot in less than a second and then it hangs for 2~3min, and repeats... It's also seemingly random the point that it hangs because subsequent installs don't hang when it had previously hanged.

Commands I have used in an attempt to fix this issue:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm cache clean --force
```

None helped whatsoever. Does anyone have any idea how I can make it install at an acceptable pace?

```
$ npm --version                                                                                                                                  
8.19.2
$ node --version                                                                                                                                   
v19.6.0
```

Comment: Maybe the speed of one of the sources is limiting your download speed

Comment: Or downgrade node.js to latest lts

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by running

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Otherwise, `npm install` spent several minutes fetching everything in the registry even when I was just trying to install a local package with the `-d` flag.